# PostgreSQL + ANALYZE + pg_statistic table

Tags: postgresql

I have question about `pg_statistic` table which stores data from ANALYZE. Could someone tell me what does columns of this table contains? I have the list [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/catalog-pg-statistic.html), but i don't know (don't understand) what is in this columns: `stanullfrac`, `stadistinct`, `stakindN`, `staopN`, `stanumbersN`, `stavaluesN`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward to me. Specially if you look inside the definition the more user-friendly pg_stat view (  `\d+ pg_stats` )

For example, say :

```
select * from pg_statistic where starelid = 23825 and staattnum=2;

starelid    | 23825      => table (oid)
staattnum   | 2          => column 2
stanullfrac | 0          =>  0% null valuess
stadistinct | -0.484307  => about 48% are distict, i.e., the average repetition is about 2
stakind1    | 1                   => code '1' : most common vals 
stavalues1  | {"John","Mary" ...  => values of most common valss
stanumbers1 | {0.0086,0.0064 ...  => percentage occurrence of common vals
stakind2    | 2                   => code '2' : histogram bounds 
stavalues2  | {-,"AAA", ...       => values (bounds) for histogram intervals
stanumbers2 | 
stakind3    | 3                   => code '3' => correlation
stavalues3  | 
stanumbers3 | {0.00826469}        => correlation coefficient
```

Same thing using the human_readable `pg_stats` view:

```
select * from pg_stats where tablename = 'persons' and attname = 'first_name';
schemaname        | public
tablename         | persons
attname           | first_name
inherited         | f
null_frac         | 0
avg_width         | 11
n_distinct        | -0.484307
most_common_vals  | {"John","Mary"...
most_common_freqs | {0.00867898,0.00640832...
histogram_bounds  | {-,"AAA"...
correlation       | 0.00826469
```

Comment: _about 48% are distict, i.e., the average repetition is about 2_ What this means?
And could You tell me what's in the `staopN` column. Next question - is there any list of data kinds (and their numbers)?

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos: It's just probability: If you throw `D` distict elements, each one with an mean repetition `n`, the expected total number is `T=nD`, hence, `1/n = D/T` (proportion of distinct elements over total elements).

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos: staopN referers to an operator, as defined in pg_operator . I don't think it's very relevant if you want to peek at the statistics, I guess it's only used internally in the optimizer.

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos: the different kinds of data are not harcoded, i.e. they could vary between pg releases. The reference, I guess, is the source, eg: http://postgresql-9.0.sourcearchive.com/documentation/9.0~beta3-2/pg__statistic_8h-source.html
See the  "Currently, three statistical slot...." comment and what follows.

Comment: Some recommended reading: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/planner-stats.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/planner-stats-details.html